# how to get only one level up directory name in php

Tags: php

is it possible to get last dirname only?
my current directory is: `http://localhost/handle/plugins/invoice_in/invoice_in_new.php`
I have try'd `realpath(__DIR__ . '/')` to get the directory level: `C:\xampp\htdocs\handle\plugins\invoice_in`

> in this address i want to get `invoice_in` separately

Comment: did you try [`basename(__DIR__)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)?

Comment: ohh noooo! i didn't. thanks @LawrenceCherone